# How to get data from two tables in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables A and B. in Table A i have details of **Subject** like `Subject_code`, `Subject_name` of all the subjects in University. In table B i have details of **Students** like `Roll_Number`, `Attendance`, `Subject_code`(that that a particular `roll_Number` has taken etc). Now i want to fetch the `Subject_name` from table A corresponding to a particular `Roll_number` from table B;

Only linking from A to B table is the `Subject_code`.

I am able to get the list of the subject_code from table A as

```
select distinct subject_code from B;
```

Now i want the names from A of all the subject whose codes i got from B.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: A simple [INNER JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx) is answer to your problem.

Comment: If it was me, I'd probably call the tables students and subjects, or something like that

Answer (score 1):

use `inner join`

```
SELECT A.* 
    FROM A inner join B on A.subject_code =B.subject_code
  where B.Roll_number =  //here enter roll number
```

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin buddy check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343796/how-to-get-data-from-two-tables-in-mysql/52343852#comment91633581_52343796

Comment: Just note the timestamp. It is with reference to a comment of yours to the OP.

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin answering depends on a lot. Just giving out query is not enough. Explanation is required for people to understand. A mere 2 minutes gap in answering times does not reflect that someone answered late. It depends a lot on their typing speed, explanation details they put in the answer, how well the answer is formatted etc. SO is not a competition. All are using their free time to help others! Dont take it otherwise!

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya not interested to any argument

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin I am not arguing. Simply suggesting that, don't make commentary on others when you cannot defend. Lets keep SO a friendly collaborative community, not a competition. Peace Out!

Answer (score 0):

Based on understanding of your limited problem description, a simple [INNER JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx) is solution to your problem. 
Try the following query ( `$input_roll_number` is your input value for a specific roll number, whose subject name you want to determine ):

```
SELECT A.roll_number, B.subject_name 
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B ON A.subject_code = B.subject_code 
WHERE A.roll_number = $input_roll_number
```

Comment: Thank you
i didn't know that we can even use the last condition after the join.

Comment: @TusharJajodia happy to help :) Happy learning!